# Include Headers on first page

Tags: notebooks, printing

I know it is possible to check the box "Include headers on first page" in the "Headers and Footers" dialog box of the Print Settings menu item, but is it also possible to check this using commands in the Notebook itself? It would be for the current notebook.

Thanks for all help, as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], PrintingOptions -> {"FirstPageHeader" -> True}]
```

You can open $InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/SystemResources/HeadersFootersDialog.nb as text file and find all possible options. For completeness I want add that with

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], PageHeaders -> {{"a1", "a2", "a3"}, {"a4", "a5", "a6"}}]
```

you can set headers. See also: [PageHeaders](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PageHeaders.html), [PageFooters](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PageFooters.html), [PageHeaderLines](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PageHeaderLines.html), [PageFooterLines](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PageFooterLines.html).

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean to copy your answer, my browser didn't refresh (a.k.a. I didn't pay attention) :)

Comment: @PinguinDirk Don't worry. Firstly I didn't read question carefully and post only the second part of my answer. When I realized my mistake I delete answer. Then I find true options and undelete it in the same time as you :)

Comment: ah that's why it appeared out of the sudden with 28mins on the timer. Advanced cheating :) I am glad my brain didn't play any tricks on me then

Comment: @ybeltukov: Why is it necessary to add the curly braces around the "PrintingOptions->..." and doesn't this command work SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], PrintingOptions -> {"FirstPageHeader" -> True}] without the "extra" curly braces? Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, they aren't necessary, I deleted them.

Comment: @Kuba, ok thanks! It seems to be necessary for me as I had also a few other Options...

Comment: @Gabriel Yes, if you want to set more options `List` is how you do this.

Answer (score 2):

As per @ybeltukov below is what I have in my stylesheet, implemented here as `SetOptions`

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
  PrintingStartingPageNumber -> 1,
  PageHeaders -> {
    {Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["Page"]}], "PageNumber"], None, None},
    {None, None, 
     Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["Page"]}], "PageNumber"]}},
  PageFooters -> {{None, None, None}, {None, None, None}},
  PrintingOptions -> {
    "PrintingMargins" -> {{90, 90}, {60, 90}},
    "PaperSize" -> {596, 794},
    "PageSize" -> {596, 794},
    "PageHeaderMargins" -> {60, 60},
    "PageFooterMargins" -> {30, 30},
    "FirstPageFace" -> Right,
    "FirstPageHeader" -> False,
    "FirstPageFooter" -> False}
    ]
```

I'd recommend having a look at the printing options settings in the options inspector and figure out what you want your base case to be, and then include those settings in a stylesheet within the "Notebook" style data.

[image]