# Adding headers and/or footers to a stylesheet

Tags: options, stylesheet, printing

I would like to push a common header(file name and page number) across multiple notebooks using one *Stylesheet*.

I know I can use the header/footer dialog on each notebook individually but this is not efficient.  A *Stylesheet* seems like the way to go.  I'm comfortable working with *Stylesheets* and applying them to notebooks.

However, I can't seem to save any changes to my header into a *Stylesheet*.  Is this even possible?  If so, how can this be done?

Comment: Your aim is not quite clear. Indeed, in the working environment form there is no division of a notebook into pages. Should your question be understood as the numeration and the file name to appear in a pdf or a printed version?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion.  And Yes.  Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, ok, so it seems that by default `PrintingOptions -> "FirstPageHeader"` is `False` [**ref**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32203/5478)

So now you can use what I've stated in comments, just add something like:

```
Cell[StyleData["Notebook", "Printout"],
 PageHeaders -> {{"a1", "a2", "a3"}, {"a1", "a2", "a3"}},
 PageFooters -> {{"a4", "a5", "a6"}, {"a4", "a5", "a6"}},
 PrintingOptions -> {"FirstPageHeader" -> True}
]
```

in your stylesheet. A minimal example:

```
CreateDocument[{x + y},
 StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData["Notebook", "Printout"],
     PageHeaders -> {{"a1", "a2", "a3"}, {"a1", "a2", "a3"}},
     PageFooters -> {{"a4", "a5", "a6"}, {"a4", "a5", "a6"}},
     PrintingOptions -> {"FirstPageHeader" -> True}
     ]
    }]
 ]
```

Comment: That was the issue.  Easy fix!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. If evaluate the second example it works. But if I incorparate the first given lines in a Stylesheet an then try to print a notebook, where this StyleSheet is set as StyleSheet the headers and footers do not appear in the printout.  What am I doing wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: @Darwin1871 Could you elaborate?

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. There was an error in the formating statement. I copied it from a working Header-Definition. And after the copying process apostrophes where missing!! Also the priorities of all the options you can set in different places is miraculous for me.